# Elasticsearch Java REST Client: see if number of eligible hits exceeded SearchSourceBuilder size

Tags: java, elasticsearch, limit

I have an Elasticsearch request:

```
SearchSourceBuilder source = new SearchSourceBuilder()
    .size(limit)
    .from(offset)
    .query(queryBuilder)
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(indexName)
        .types(type)
        .source(source);
SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest);
```

I need to optionally return a pagination token based on whether or not the number of results returned was limited by the `limit` parameter (in other words, are there more results to return). Is there a way to see if the number of eligible search hits that matched the query exceeded `limit`, other than either doing another query, or by setting the size to `limit + 1` and removing the last hit in the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch returns the total number of documents matching your query in `hits.totalHits` property in the response. If it is bigger than `offset+limit` then you have next page.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you need is first just a count search, with this I mean do the query you want and set the `size` to `0` this make the result to just return the total hits, where you can get the size of each page.

```
    int pageSize = 10;
    long totalCount = searchResponse.getHits().getTotalHits();
    PageCount pageCount = new PageCount();
    if (totalCount <= 0)
        return result;
    long pages = (totalCount < pageSize) ? 1l : ((totalCount % pageSize) == 0) ? (totalCount / pageSize) : ((totalCount / pageSize) + 1);

    if (totalCount <= 10000) {
        result.setTotal(totalCount);
        result.setPages(pages);
    } else {
        result.setTotal(10000);
        result.setPages((10000 / pageSize));
    }
```

Here I use the 10000 just as a limit so that Elasticsearch to limit the amount of memory it consumes. Once you have this information you can return the number of pages for the query and make requests for a given page.

Once you have this, you could setup the search request like:

```
    long size = ((pageCount.getTotal() < pageSize) ? pageCount.getTotal() : pageSize);
    if (pageCount.getTotal() > pageSize && (page + 1) >= pageCount.getPages()) {
        size = ((pageCount.getTotal() % pageSize) != 0 ? pageCount.getTotal() % pageSize : pageSize);
    }
    searchRequest.setSize((int) size).setFrom((int) (page * pageSize))
```

This is just sample code, I hope this get you enough.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like I can get the totalHits property from the original query. It turns out this is equal to the total number of possible results matching the query, and is unaffected by the size limit.